# How to import only certain comments from post[s]

Tags: comments, import, wordpress.com-hosting

> **NOTICE:** This is solely NOT a WordPress.com Question, but related to WordPress Migration and Export-Import.

I [started blogging in WordPress.com](http://soothtruth.wordpress.com) and then shifted my blog to a [self-hosted site](http://www.soothtruthbd.com). But even after that, I din't shut down my **.com** blog for some internal reasons. Though I stopped updating the **.com** blog, users are still commenting there. But after a long time, I now determined to shut down the **.com** site. But before that, I want to import some of the new comments, those posted after the migration.

Suppose, post#5 had 3 comments, when I migrated, now it has 5 comments — so, 2 new comments are in post#5.

As because I have to Export `.xml` data from the **.com** site, and the `.xml` contains all the post comments etc. in it. So, I've to find out a way that only import and add, but doesn't duplicate and/or delete and/or overwrite any of my site's present post content or comments or any other settings.

Is that really possible?

#### EDIT

What I got so far is the `.xml`, and I got that the comment resides under `<wp:comment>` under each `<item>` with the `$post_id` and others:

```
<item>
 <wp:post_id>$post_id</wp:post_id>
 <wp:comment>$comment</wp:comment>
</item>
```

I've actually no idea about how to proceed with WordPress `.xml` data file.

Comment: have you try anything if yes then show,

Comment: I made an edit to the Question with what I tried.

Comment: I'd try to search for an XML editor, where you can see all the nodes in hierarchy and remove the duplicate ones. Then, it should save the file preserving the *importable* structure.

Comment: There is a plugin called Wordpress [Comments Imports & Exports](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comments-import-export-woocommerce/), which allows to export comments of the old WP site. Among the various options you can specify a starting date for the export. In this way only the comments posted after the migration will be exported. Then you can import the CSV file with these comments on the new site.It worked perfectly for me.